# Displaying an error message on a visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, exception, error-messages, custom-controller

So I'm trying to display an error message on a visualforce page using

```
ApexPages.addMessage
```

or

```
ApexPages.addMessages
```

As suggested in numerous threads and posts like this one: https://www.interactiveties.com/blog/2015/visualforce-apex-pagemessages.php

On my visualforce page I have

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageMessages></apex:pageMessages>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

but nothing is actually popping up there.

In my controller class I add a message like this:

```
public PageReference exchangeInv() {
  if (opp.StageName == 'Contract Executed') {

    // do some stuff

    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+opp.Id);
    return pageRef;
  }
  else {
    ApexPages.addMessages(new applicationException('error'));
    return null;
  }
}
```

It will get into that else case where I expect it to, and that error message will show up in the log, but will not show up inside

```
<apex:pageMessages>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: When is your `exchangeInv()` method called?

Comment: It's called by a button on the visualforce page the user will press once they have made their desired changes to the line item.

Comment: Can you replace "ApexPages.addMessages(new applicationException('error'));" with "ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'my error msg');" OR "ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'my error msg'));"

Comment: Ya I tried with a ApexPages.Message just like that, and that didn't display anything either :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `rerender` pageMessages section by commandButton's attribute

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageMessages id="msgId"/>


    <apex:commandButton name="Submit" action="{!exchangeInv}" rerender ="msgId"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Take this approach:

> Since you are throwing `applicationException`, so better to use `throw new applicationException` and in the catch block, wrap that message into `pageMessages`

```
public PageReference exchangeInv() 
{
    try
    {
        if (opp.StageName == 'Contract Executed') {
        // do some stuff
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+opp.Id);
        return pageRef;
      }
      else {
        throw new applicationException('error');
        return null;
      }
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, ex.getMessage());
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
        return null;
    }  
}
```

> or, if you don't want to use `applicationException` then use the error into pageMessages as follows:

```
public PageReference exchangeInv() 
{

    if (opp.StageName == 'Contract Executed') {
        // do some stuff
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+opp.Id);
        return pageRef;
      }
      else {
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'error');
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
        return null;
      }

}
```

Comment: Yes! Using the render property on my command button did the trick! Thanks for the help. And I think I will restructure my code as per your suggestion and wrap my code in a try catch block, easier to follow I think.