# Basic search functinality

Tags: apex

I need Basic Search functionality where i need to search for Users information with the help of Email Id or User Number or Bid Number only one search box has to be there and also if there are related information i need to throw an error.

---

below is my rough code which is working fine for other fields , which i tried but , its showing three columns which i dont need also i need to populate an error.

```
    <apex:page controller="Searchname">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:PageBlock >
  <apex:PageBlockSection >
  <apex:PageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:outputLabel > Name</apex:outputLabel>
  <apex:inputText value="{!name}"/>
  </apex:PageBlockSectionItem>
   <apex:PageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:outputLabel >Title</apex:outputLabel>
  <apex:inputText value="{!title}"/>
  </apex:PageBlockSectionItem>
  <apex:PageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:outputLabel >Department</apex:outputLabel>
  <apex:inputText value="{!department}"/>
 </apex:PageBlockSectionItem>
  <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!executeSearch}"/>
  </apex:PageBlockSection>
  <apex:PageBlockTable var="act" value="{!mycar}"> 
  <apex:column value="{!act.name}"/>  
  //<apex:column value="{!act.Title}"/> 
  //<apex:column value="{!act.Department}"/>
  </apex:PageBlockTable>
  </apex:PageBlock>
  <apex:PageBlock >
  <!--apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!edit}"/-->
  </apex:PageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>


  public with sharing class Searchname {
    public String name { get; set;}
    Public String title {get; set;}
    Public String department{get; set;}
    public list<User> mycar { get; set; }
    public boolean searched{get;set;}
    public searchname() {
    searched=false;
    string namestr=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('name');
    string namestr1=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('title');
    string namestr2=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('department');
    if(null!=namestr || null!=namestr1 || null!=namestr2 ) {
    name=namestr;
    title=namestr1;
    //title=namestr1;
    //executeSearch();
    }
    }
    public PageReference executeSearch() {
      searched=true;
    System.debug('name' +name);
    string searchstr=('%'+name+'%');
    System.debug(searchstr);
   // accounts= new List<User>();
    mycar=[select id,Name,title,Department from User where name Like:searchstr and title Like:searchstr and Department Like:searchstr  ];
    System.debug(mycar);
        return null;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you share your approach or code what you have tried so far

Comment: Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask] and [answer]. You can always comment on or [edit] your own posts. Please familiarize yourself with the rules and expectations of this site.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of syntactic or logical issues in your code. I'm going to pull out and highlight a few here, but please don't take this as comprehensive.

I would strongly urge you to make use of Trailhead to build your foundational skills - without a little more grounding, you may be very frustrated working on a project like this.

### Extra Columns

Your Visualforce page has three columns because you do this:

```
  <apex:PageBlockTable var="act" value="{!mycar}"> 
  <apex:column value="{!act.name}"/>  
  //<apex:column value="{!act.Title}"/> 
  //<apex:column value="{!act.Department}"/>
  </apex:PageBlockTable>
```

The comment syntax in Visualforce is that of HTML:

```
<!-- this is a comment -->
```

Apex/Java/C style `//` comments have no effect on Visualforce at all.

### Null Handling in Constructor

Your constructor attempts to identify `null` values in incoming data, but it does so incorrectly.

```
if(null!=namestr || null!=namestr1 || null!=namestr2 ) {
name=namestr;
title=namestr1;
//title=namestr1;
//executeSearch();
}
```

Because of the way you've put together your conditionals, you will populate your instance variables `name` and `title` when any of the values `namestr`, `namestr1`, and `namestr2` are non-`null`. You'd want separate conditionals for each incoming parameter, if you needed to do this - you don't. Instance variables are initialized to `null` anyway, which you need to be aware of later as it can lead to `NullPointerException`.

### Query Criteria

Your search function goes like this, with commented lines removed:

```
    public PageReference executeSearch() {
      searched=true;
    mycar=[select id,Name,title,Department from User where name Like:searchstr and title Like:searchstr and Department Like:searchstr  ];
        return null;
    }
```

Your logic here is probably not what you want. Using `AND` means that all of your criteria are required to match. Since you're using the same `searchstr` variable here (which you've set equal to `name`), you're really only searching on a single value, so your query will probably return no results in most cases.

What you actually want *may* be [SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm), Salesforce's full-text search language. However, if you wish to use SOQL, you need to think out your query carefully. How are you using the user's input values, and which fields do they match against?

You may need to utilize [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to fully meet your objective, once you are clearer about what that objective is. This would allow you to construct a query dynamically based on which values have been populated. Note that Dynamic SOQL comes with unique challenges, including the requirement to escape user input via `String.escapeSingleQuotes()` to avoid injection attacks.

### Adding Errors

To surface errors to the user, you should take some time to review the [`<apex:pageMessages>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm) component documentation, and the `ApexPages.addMessage()` function. You can find a quick review of both here on [Salesforce Stack Exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191078/displaying-an-error-message-on-a-visualforce-page).

Comment: +1 simply for taking the time to write out an answer that is more detailed than the original question.